# vector fit interpretation NMDS

Tags: r, correlation, pca, r-squared

So a colleague and myself are using principal component analysis (PCA) or non metric multidimensional scaling (NMDS) to examine how environmental variables influence patterns in benthic community composition. A common method is to fit environmental vectors on to an ordination. The length and direction of the vectors seems somewhat straighforward but I don't understand how an R squared value or a p-value is calculated for these vectors. I have looked at a dozen papers and the most I can gather is that these numbers are calculated using permutations of the data. This does not seem very intuitive. What data is being permuted? How does this permutation create an R squared value and what variance is being explained? My limited understanding of an R squared value comes from linear regressions. I need to explain this to people who have little to no background in statistics so any help understanding these concepts or a link to an available text would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vector fitting *is* a regression. Explicitly, the model fitted is

$$y = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon$$

where $y$ is the environmental variable requiring a vector, $X_i$ is the $i$th ordination "axis" score (here for the first two ordination "axes") and $\varepsilon$ the unexplained variance. Both $y$ and $X_i$ are centred prior to fitting the model, hence no intercept. The $\hat{\beta}_j$ are the coordinates of the vector for $y$ in the ordination space spanned by the $i$ ordination axes; these may be normalised to unit length.

As this is a regression, $R^2$ is easily computed and so could the significance of the coefficients or $R^2$. However, we presume that the model assumptions are not fully met and hence we use a permutation test to test significance of the $R^2$ of the model.

The permutation test doesn't create the overall $R^2$, what is done is that we permute the values of the response $y$ into random order. Next we use the fitted regression model (equation above) to *predict* the randomised response data and compute the $R^2$ between the randomised response and the fitted values from the model. This $R^2$ value is recorded and then the procedure is done again with a different random permutation. We keep doing this a modest number of times (say 999). Under the null hypothesis of no relationship between the ordination "axis" scores and the environmental variable, the observed $R^2$ value should be a common value among the permuted $R^2$ values. If however the observed $R^2$ is extreme relative to the permutation distribution of $R^2$ then it is unlikely that the Null hypothesis is correct as we have substantial evidence against it. The proportion of times a randomised $R^2$ from the distribution is equal to or greater than the observed $R^2$ is a value known as the permutation $p$ value.

An example, fully worked may help with this. Using the **vegan** package for R and some in-built data

```
require(vegan)
data(varespec)
data(varechem)

## fit PCA
ord <- rda(varespec)

## fit vector for Al - gather data
dat <- cbind.data.frame(Al = varechem$Al,
                        scores(ord, display = "sites", scaling = 1))

## fit the model
mod <- lm(Al ~ PC1 + PC2, data = dat)
summary(mod)
```

This gives

```
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = Al ~ PC1 + PC2, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-172.30  -58.00  -12.54   58.44  239.46 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  142.475     19.807   7.193 4.34e-07 ***
PC1           31.143      9.238   3.371  0.00289 ** 
PC2           27.492     13.442   2.045  0.05356 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 97.04 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4254,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3707 
F-statistic: 7.774 on 2 and 21 DF,  p-value: 0.002974
```

Note the value for the `Multiple R-squared` (0.4254).

**vegan** has a canned function for doing all of this, on multiple environmental variables at once; `envfit()`. Compare the $R^2$ from above with the vector-fitted value (to keep things simple I just do `Al` here, but you could pass all of `varechem` and `envfit` would fit vectors [centroids for factors] for all variables.)

```
set.seed(42) ## make this reproducible - pseudo-random permutations!
envfit(ord, varechem[, "Al", drop = FALSE])

> envfit(ord, varechem[, "Al", drop = FALSE])

***VECTORS

       PC1     PC2     r2 Pr(>r)   
Al 0.85495 0.51871 0.4254  0.004 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
P values based on 999 permutations.
```

The two $R^2$ values shown are exactly the same.

[Do note that `envfit` doesn't actually fit models via `lm` internally - it uses a QR decomposition. This is the same methods employed deeper down in `lm` but we call it directly to fit the model manually as we want it without the extra things that something like `lm.fit` would give us.]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and thank you for laying out the answer so clearly. I really appreciate it.