# Environmental variable vector in NMDS

Tags: r, regression, correlation, vegan

I am using Non-metric MultiDimensional Scaling (NMDS) on a Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix.
Then, I am trying to link the resulting NMDS axes (let's say "components") to environmental variables, as done by the `envfit` function from R package `vegan` (but **without** using this package) and described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56427/vector-fit-interpretation-nmds). My objective is to plot the variable vectors in the NMDS space (as illustrated [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Nonmetric-multidimensional-scaling-NMDS-ordination-of-lakes-n-44-based-on-water_fig1_273295017)).

However, it is not clear in both the literature and in the package documentation whether each environmental variable **and/or** explanatory NMDS components should be scaled (i.e. by subtracting its mean and/or dividing by its standard deviation) before processing the analysis. This directly affects the regression coefficients and therefore the vector coordinates (i.e. the arrow length in the plot).

I tried many times scaling or not the variables (and NMDS components) before processing the regressions, but the vector lengths always exceeds the NMDS axis scales. What am I doing wrong?
Is there some sort of "vector rescaling" needed before plotting, as describe [in this tutorial](https://archetypalecology.wordpress.com/2018/02/18/non-metric-multidimensional-scaling-nmds-what-how/) saying that vectors should be scaled by square root of r2?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 2005 vegan tutorial: https://tinyurl.com/yxbt9ry3
I only skimmed it looking for something different, but it seems scaling is implemented in the function.

Comment: I checked this tutorial. As described in the one I cited, the vegan packages only specifies that the Dims (vectors) should be scaled by the square root of r2. But what does "scaled" mean?

Comment: I'm not use if I get your question correctly. Are you asking why you should scale data, e.g. what the purpose of scaling is?

Comment: My question is: what "scaling" means here. There are many ways to "scale" in statistics. Does it mean multiplying, dividing, ... the Dims (vectors) by the square root of r2?